# How to create a button with gradient color and an icon in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native

Like the title says, I want to ask if there's a way to create a button with gradient color and an icon in React Native? I know that gradient color can't be added without an external library, so I tried this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gradient-buttons

However, I can't see a way to add Icon as a props to the gradient buttons of this library. The answer doesn't have to use the library, I would just like to know a convenient way to achieve the button I described. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own button with an icon like below

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

const GradientButton = ({ onPress, style, colors, text, renderIcon }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <LinearGradient colors={colors} style={style}>
        {renderIcon()}
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Usage would be

```
  <GradientButton
    onPress={() => alert('Button Pressed')}
    style={{
      padding: 15,
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderRadius: 5,
      flexDirection: 'row',
    }}
    colors={['#874f00', '#f5ba57']}
    text="Press"
    renderIcon={() => (
      <Ionicons
        name="md-checkmark-circle"
        size={20}
        color="green"
        style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}
      />
    )}
  />
```

You will have more control over the button and change it anyway you want, you can add more props to customize it the way you want.

You can try out the demo here
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/gradientbutton

The above icon and gradient packages are for expo
You can use [RN Vector icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) and [Linear gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) package as well

Answer (score 0):

In the docs of the package you provided it shows an example like this:

```
     <GradientButton
          style={{ marginVertical: 8 }}
          textStyle={{ fontSize: 20 }}
          gradientBegin="#874f00"
          gradientEnd="#f5ba57"
          gradientDirection="diagonal"
          height={60}
          width={300}
          radius={15}
          impact
          impactStyle='Light'
          onPressAction={() => alert('You pressed me!')}
    >
      Gradient Button #2
    </GradientButton>
```

Maybe try adding your icon in between the tags instead of as prop?

Comment: Actually, this answers the question. I tried to put the Icon and Text -elements inside the GradientButton tags. They could also be arranged next to each other with nesting them inside a View with flexDirection: row. However, what happened was that adding the View element inside the GradientButton tags caused textStyle not to influence the Text, and meanwhile the style that I tried to add as Text props didn't also work. Didn't find a way to add the "flexDirection: row" to GradientButton style-props either so, this caused a deadlock where either flexDirection or textStyle had to be left out.

Comment: Not sure if I understood what u tried. Have you tried adding "flexDirection: row" directly to the style prop of the GardientButton? At least the [docs](https://github.com/thomaswang/react-native-gradient-buttons#props) suggest that it should work.

Comment: There was a bug, as I used textDecorationColor instead of color in my TextStyles... I'm now confident that your answer would've worked fine. Still ended up going with the TouchableOpacity / LinearGradient combo.